# Contextual Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I have a list of comma separated words that I want to remove the comma from and replace with a space:

```
elements-(a,b,c,d)
```

becomes:

```
elements-(a b c d)
```

The question is how can I do this using a regular expression if and only if that list is within a specific context, e.g. only prefixed by element-():

The following:

`There are a number of elements-(a,b,c,d) and a number of other elements-(e,f,g,h)`

should become:

```
There are a number of elements-(a b c d) and a number of other elements-(e f g h)
```

What would be the correct way to do this with regex?

Comment: Someone answered your question, so you should identify their answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For contextual regular expressions, you can use [zero-width look-around assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).  Look-around assertions are used to assert that something must be true in order for the match to succeed, but they do not consume any characters (hence "zero-width").

In your case, you want to use positive look-behind and look-ahead assertions.  In C#, you can do the following:

```
    static string Replace(string text)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(
            text,
            @"(?<=elements\-\((\w+,)*)(\w+),(?=(\w+,)*\w+\))",
            "$2 "
        );
    }
```

There are three basic parts to the pattern here (in order):

1. `(?<=elements\-\((\w+,)*)` - this is the positive look-behind assertion.  It says that the pattern will only match if it is preceded by the text `elements-(` and zero-or-more comma-separated strings.
2. `(\w+),` - this is the actual match.  It's the text that's being replaced.
3. `(?=(\w+,)*\w+\))` - this is the positive look-ahead assertion.  It says that the pattern will only match if it is followed by one-or-more comma-separated strings.

In C#, for matching the inner comma-separated contents, you can alternatively do the following:

```
    static string Replace(string text)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(
            text,
            @"(?<=elements\-)\(((\w+,)+\w+)\)",
            m => string.Format("({0})", m.Groups[1].Value.Replace(',', ' '))
        );
    }
```

The basic approach with the positive look-ahead assertion is still the same.

Example output:

`"(x,y,z) elements-(a,b) (m,m,m) elements-(c,d,e,f,g,h)"`

...becomes...

`"(x,y,z) elements-(a b) (m,m,m) elements-(c d e f g h)"`